# RegEx for matching X digits with one optional comma in between digits?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a RegExp to match only 8 digits, with one optional comma maybe hidden in-between the digits.

All of these should match:

```
12345678
12,45678
123456,8
```

Right now I have:

```
^[0-9,]{8}
```

but of course that erroneously matches `012,,,67`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/dX9aS9/1

I know optionals exist but don't understand how to keep the 8 digit length applying to the comma while also keeping the comma limited to 1.

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can there be leading or trailing commas?

Comment: I don't think it matters for my example but it might be good to understand that solution as well if you know it.

Comment: I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match 8 char string that can only contain digits and an optional comma in-between, you may use

```
^(?=.{8}$)\d+,?\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN8bM5/4)

The lookahead will require the string to contain 8 chars. `,?` will make matching a comma optional, and the `+` after `\d` will require at least 1 digit before and after an optional comma.

If you need to match a string that has 8 digits and an optional comma, you can use

```
^(?:(?=.{9}$)\d+,\d+|\d{8})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN8bM5/1)

Actually, the string will have 9 characters in the string (if it has a comma), or just 8 - if there are only digits.

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?=.{9}$)\d+,\d+|\d{8})` - 2 alternatives:

  - `(?=.{9}$)\d+,\d+` - 1+ digits followed with 1 comma followed with 1+ digits, and the whole string matched should be 9 char long (8 digits and 1 comma)
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{8}` - 8 digits
- `$` - end of string

See the [Java code demo](http://ideone.com/Qieg0D) (note that with `String#matches()`, the `^` and `$` anchors at the start and end of the pattern are redundant and can be omitted since the pattern is anchored by default when used with this method):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("0123,,678", "0123456", // bad
        "01234,567", "01234567" // good
    );
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.matches("(?:(?=.{9}$)\\d+,\\d+|\\d{8})"));
```

**NOTE FOR LEADING/TRAILING COMMAS:**

You just need to replace `+` (*match 1 or more occurrences*) quantifiers to `*` (*match 0 or more occurrences*) in the first alternative branch to allow leading/trailing commas:

```
^(?:(?=.{9}$)\d*,\d*|\d{8})$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN8bM5/2)

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer! Should help others down the road as well, plus I learned more about RegExp :).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Can you recheck the test result. It will fail for input 12,45678

Comment: `12,45678` has 7 digits, not 8. *I'm trying to write a RegExp to match only 8 digits, with one optional comma maybe hidden in-between the digits.* - is it a correct requirement?

Comment: Yes, I guess I meant 8 characters so either 8 digits or 7 digits and 1 comma.

Comment: I added that regex to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regex if you want to let trailing comma:

```
^((\d,?){8})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX9aS9/4)

Otherwise use following one:

```
^((\d,?){8})(?<!,)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX9aS9/3)

`(?<!,)` is a [negative-lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

/`^(?!\d{0,6},\d{0,6},\d{0,6})(?=\d[\d,]{6}\d).{8}$/`

I guess this cooperation of positive and negative look-ahead does just what's asked. If you remove the start and end delimiters and set the g flag then it will try to match the pattern along decimal strings longer than 8 characters as well.

Please try http://regexr.com/3d63m

Explanation: The negative look ahead `(?!\d{0,6},\d{0,6},\d{0,6})` tries not to find any commas side by side if they have 6 or less decimal characters in between while the positive look ahead `(?=\d[\d,]{6}\d)` tries to find 6 decimal or comma characters in between two decimal characters. And the last `.{8}` selects 8 characters.